# How do I get sentences including links?

Tags: scrapy

I would like to collect the Japanese articles searched by google. I try to extract Japanese sentences, then I run the following code in order to get the tag including the most Japanese words.

```
texts = mostTag.xpath('<<path>>/text()').extract()
text = ''
for s in texts:
    text += s
```

But, this code has a problem in such cases as the article has a link between sentences as below.

```
<div class="sample">
  <p>
    "A"
    <a href="link.html">B</a>
    "C"
  </p>
</div>
```

In this case, my program get AC but what I want is ABC. I appreciate it if anyone tell me how to get the sentence as 'ABC'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `string()`:

```
text = mostTag.xpath('string(//div[@class="sample"])').extract_first()
```

Or use [html2text](https://pypi.org/project/html2text/)